# How to implement constant velocity and collisions without gravity

Tags: android, andengine

I am learning game development and i am trying to implement the AndEngineBox2D Extension such that my character is always moving at a constant velocity, when it collides with a body sprite, the character automatically changes direction (is deflected) and moves in the new direction until another collision has happened and the same is done repeatedly.

My Question:
Is it possible to implement the changes in trajectory  with AndEngineBox2D's physics world or i have to to handle it manually is java code.

Comment: In your question you describe 'constant velocity' and not 'constant acceleration'. Thus your question title and your question do not match up.

Comment: There seem to be 2 questions here: about implementing constant velocity in Box2D and about... whether Box2D works?

Answer (score -1):

You will need to do it manually for best effect. Unless you want a less polished looking deflection.